# How to create a new LinearLayout for each three button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a new `LinearLayout` for each three buttons created. What I want is to order numbers, something like this:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

To do that. I need to create a new `LinearLayout` as `HORIZONTAL`. But how to create a new `LinearLayout` in loop?

```
for (int i=1:i<=9:i++) {
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText(""+i);
    // I need to do something here and put my general layout
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a [GridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) instead. It will create a balanced 3x3 grid much more reliably and with less code.

---

**Addition**
But since you are apparently constrained to LinearLayouts try:

```
LinearLayout outer = new LinearLayout(this);
outer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout inner;
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if(i % 3 == 0) {
        inner = new LinearLayout(this);
        outer.addView(inner);
    }

    // Create your Buttons and add them to inner
}
setContentView(outer);
```

Comment: yeah you are right but i need to do with LinearLayout. This is must.

Comment: sorry but does not compile. i Get project_name has stopped error

Comment: I had an error `i % 0` should be `i % 3`, did you notice that update?